# How do I add a List of Algorithms to mythesis.cls?

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

Currently I am using the `algorithmic` and `algorithm` packages for generating algorithms in my thesis using the `mythesis` class.

I tried simply using `\listofalgorithms` but it does not give the same format as my List of Figures/Tables and it doesn't get added to the Table of Contents.

I went into the class file and found this code related to the table of figures:

```
%
%   List of figures
%
\def\textofLoF#1{\gdef\@textofLoF{#1}}  \textofLoF{List of Figures}
\def\listoffigures{\chapter*{\@textofLoF\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofLoF}
   {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
   \@starttoc{lof}
    }
   }
%
```

So I tried duplicating this in the class for a list of algorithms:

```
%   List of algorithms
%
\def\textofLoAl#1{\gdef\@textofLoAl{#1}}  \textofLoAl{List of Algorithms}
\def\listofalgorithms{\chapter*{\@textofLoAl\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofLoAl}
   {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
   \@starttoc{loal}
    }
   }
```

but now I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \listofalgorithms already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

I am assuming this is due to the conflict of `\listofalgorithms` already defined in one of the packages. So I tried replacing `\listofalgorithms` in the previous code with `\listofalgs`, at which it compiles successfully, but the List of Algorithms is empty.

I noticed in my file directory that after compiling there is a file called `Thesis.lof`, containing a list of all the figures, and also a `Thesis.loal`, but this file is empty. I have no idea how TeX populates this `Thesis.lof` file, does anybody know? With this knowledge I should be able to duplicate it for the List of Algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your setup is that you're adding the `\listofalgorithms` to `mythesis.cls`. This means that `\listofalgorithms` gets defined when you load your class

```
\documentclass[..]{mythesis}
```

Subsequently you load [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm) which tries to create `\listofalgorithms` via a `\newcommand`, and this fails.

Instead, use

```
\def\textofLoAl#1{\gdef\@textofLoAl{#1}}
\textofLoAl{List of Algorithms}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\listofalgorithms{%
    \chapter*{\@textofLoAl}
    \@mkboth{}{}%
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofLoAl}%
    {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
     \@starttoc{loa}
    }%
  }}
```

which should delay your `\def`inition until `\begin{document}`.

Note that I've used `\@starttoc{loa}` since the `algorithm` package writes algorithm `\caption`s to a `.loa` file, not a `.loal` file.

Ideally one shouldn't modify the `.cls` directly. Instead, write modifications in a separate style file, or as part of your preamble (possibly wrapping it with a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair).